# There are no LoginController and RegisterController in my Laravel Setup

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am currently following this [tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial). Currently, at the point where I need to adjust controller for register and login. There supposed to be RegisterController and LoginController in app/Http/Controllers/Auth but there are none.

A documentation I saw suggested to run `php artisan make:auth` but after ran this command my Auth folder is still empty. I am using the latest Laravel (Laravel Framework 5.6.17). So, how can I have RegisterController and LoginController?

EDIT: I just realized that RegisterController and LoginController will be generated with `php artisan make:auth` only for new, fresh, scafolded Laravel project. The command does not generate RegisterController and LoginController for old project. What should I do?

Comment: RegisterController and LoginController come with a fresh Laravel project, you don't need to use `php artisan make:auth`. You can always just copy them [from Github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth)

Comment: Hmm after making a new project again it seems that they are there. IDK, why they are not in my old project though.

Comment: you can overwrite the function and make your own Register and Login Controller

Comment: I still use `php artisan make:auth` everytime when I start a fresh Laravel v5.2 project. What makes it not generating controllers in your **old project**? Do you have any error reports?

Comment: Everything went alright, but the controller is no where to be found. I do not know what happened either.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily download fresh copies of these controllers from the github repo.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/v5.6.12/app/Http/Controllers/Auth